# Spring Security and CAS

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I have some question that depends on initegration Spring Security 3 and CAS technology.
I know that SS gives me abilities to setup CAS auth with some providers and filters. But I didn`t see examples that describe how can I use my custom login form or page.
CAS gives options to setup custom design of login page, but this solution isn`t for me.
I need to implement pop-up login form in my applications. This is requirement and I can`t change anything.

So, my question is:
How can I integrate Spring Security and CAS with my custom login form/page?
Give me some examples or thematic links about this question, please.

Or maybe I mustn`t use CAS. Maybe some OpenId techonology?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of basic principles of CAS: actual application does not know anything about user password. So if you absolutely want to have login page with password then consider using some other technology. For example if you can add for each your application a sub domain then authentication based on domain coockie will be good enough (consider Google with docs.google.com, mail.google.com, etc...)

Comment: Thanks, Maksym. One more question. Spring Security doesn`t have any troubles with session across subdomains? Do you some examples of this method?